# Access (read/write) to virtual memory process from another application

Tags: c, linux, virtual-memory

I have simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 5;

int
main(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        int i;
        sleep(1);
        printf("%p %i\n", &a, a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output (Ubuntu x64):

```
0x601048 5
0x601048 5
0x601048 5
0x601048 5
```

I was learning about pointers in C and I already know that you can use `memcpy` to write data wherever (almost) you want within virtual memory of process. But, is it possible to modify value of `int a`, placed at `0x601048` address, by using another application(which is of course using its own virtual memory)? How to do this? I'm interested in solutions only for C.

Comment: Short answer: no.  The virtual address space of each process is completely independent of any others.

Comment: Each process has its own virtual address space and a process cannot access the virtual address space of another process.

Comment: Slightly longer answer than 'no': `ptrace`. Debuggers like `gdb` need to be able to do exactly this.

Comment: Yeah, ptrace is the answer on Linux. It's a system call that allows you to inspect the memory and registers of a different process.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth us2012
So how can I explain to myself that I am able to change values of specific address using software like CheatEngine? Is that similar situation, isn't it? Maybe I have to write application that loads first one and then I'll have access to its virtual memory?

Comment: Cheating tools will *probably* use `ptrace`. Basile Starynkevitch has a great list of options in his answer, but many of them are for when you want two processes to mutually agree on sharing memory. In order to break into another process and change its memory, you'd probably use `ptrace`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not easily possible (to share virtual memory between two different processes on Linux). As a first approximation, code as it if was not possible.

And even if you did share such memory, you'll get into *synchronization* issues.

You really should read books like [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com). They have several chapters on that issue (which is complex).

Usually, if you really want to share memory, you won't share some memory on the call stack, but you would "reserve" some memory zone to be later shared.

You could read a lot more about

- [pthread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pthread)-s (e.g. read this [pthread tutprial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/))
- shared memory segments set up with [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) using `MAP_SHARED`
- low level debugging facilities using [ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) notably `PTRACE_PEEKDATA`
- old SysV shared memory using [shmat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmat.2.html)
- Posix shared memory (see [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)...) using [shm_open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html)
- `/proc/` file system [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) e.g. `/proc/$PID/mem` ; I strongly suggest to look at `file:///proc/self/maps` at first in your browser and to read more till you understand what that is showing you. (you could `mmap` some other's process `/proc/$PID/mem` ....)
- `/dev/mem` (the physical RAM) see [mem(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/mem.4.html)
- loading a kernel module doing insane tricks.

**I strongly advise against playing such dirty memory tricks** for a beginner. If you insist, be prepared to break your system and backup it often. Don't play such tricks while a Linux novice.

<sup>Often you'll need `root` privileges. See [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)</sup>

Comment: Your answer is great but what if I don't want to share memory or reserve some for later? I think CheatEngine is the best example of what I want to do. It's application which loads another process and then you can change values of its addresses? So how is it possible?

Comment: **Don't do that.** But my answer is exhaustive enough to give you several possibilities to violate the memory.

Comment: Don't worry. It's just curiosity. Thank you :)

Comment: Can you share any working example, where I can read a file from a application (Application A) which is locked for being written by another application (Application B)?